# Sending push notification with pyapns with priority

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pyapns

I'm sending ios notifications through apns with the following code:

```
from apns import APNs, Payload

apns = APNs(cert_file='***.pem',key_file='***.pem')
payload = Payload(alert=message, badge=1)
apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token, payload)
```

is there an option to send it with higher priority? Some users are getting the notifications with a significant delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use "priority" parameter here is sample, but I can`t guarantee that notification will be received immediately.

```
import time
from apns import APNs, Frame, Payload

apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='cert.pem', key_file='key.pem')

# Send a notification
token_hex = 'b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b87'
payload = Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default", badge=1)
apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)

# Send multiple notifications in a single transmission
frame = Frame()
identifier = 1
expiry = time.time()+3600
priority = 10
frame.add_item('b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b87', payload, identifier, expiry, priority)
apns.gateway_server.send_notification_multiple(frame)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting:
'GatewayConnection' object has no attribute '_sent_notifications'
as an error from apns.py on self._sent_notifications += frame.get_notifications(self)